# Sharepoint 2007 - creation of another site collection within a intranet web application

Tags: sharepoint

What would be the best way/ steps to create a SHAREPOINT 2007 SITE which any one can browse through in our situation?
We already have a web application in our production which is used as a authoring site and a extended application for that site collection,  were the public can access it without authentication.

Can I create another SITE COLLECTION under the current web application and then create a required web page in it?

Thanks
Jag

Answer (score 0):

You can create many site collections per web application. Just go to the Central Administration console and under Sharepoint Site Management, (Under Application Management), click Create site collection. You will then be asked to select the web application under which you want to create it.

Note too that the url will appear something like webappname/sites/sitecollection

hope this helps,
sivilian

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I aready have a web application which has a site for authoring content (intranet) and then a internet site which is a extended web application of the current web application. can I create a new site collection in this web application and configure into to a internet site? What would be the steps to do that??

Comment: If you already have the extended web application configured for the internet, the new site collection should automatically be visible there. There is no configuration needed.

Comment: So should I create a site collection under the extended web application ? Can it have its own database ?? Any help in direction will help ?